# How to set a public reactive property in the declared component during component construction

Tags: lightning-web-components, public-reactive-properties

I'm reading about lwc properties and came across a statement.

> *A component that declares a public reactive property can’t set the property value, **except at component construction time**. A parent
>   component that uses the component in its markup can set the
>   component’s public property value. In our example, the c-todoitem
>   component can’t update the value of the itemName property in the
>   todoitem.js file.*

Based on the above statement I can't set a public reactive property(`@api`), except for the component construction time. I know we can use getters and setters to set the value, but it does involve declaring a private reactive property(`@track`).

In this context what is the meaning of ***component construction time***. Is there another way to set the value of public reactive properties in the declared component without the interference of the private reactive properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply means that you need to set the value in just one of two places. Both will be demonstrated here, as well as what's not:

```
export default class AppName extends LightningElement {
  @api message1 = 'Default message'; // allowed
  @api message2;
  constructor() {
    super(); // must be called, and must be called before using 'this'
    this.message2 = 'New default message'; // also allowed
  }
  onclickhandler() {
    this.message1 = 'Try to change on click...'; // not allowed
  }
}
```

Note that the constructor is always called `constructor`, unlike Java and other languages where the constructor is the class' name.

---

After defining it either inline or via constructor, you are no longer allowed to modify the property at all. It becomes read-only. If you want to be able to communicate to the parent component, the get/set combination is required.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation, I was able to test the default message however when I try testing _New default message_ Eslint throws a [super error](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/constructor-super). Couple of ways I tried  `constructor() {this.message1 = 'New default message'; // also allowed
  }` and `@api message2 ;constructor(message2){ this.message2 = 'New default message'; // also allowed }`

Comment: @codeyinthecloud I cleaned up the code to include a proper demonstration, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great, `super();` does the trick. Thanks again, sometimes It's hard to move forward in the documentation being stuck at once place! You saved my day!

Comment: @codeyinthecloud I've already put something like 10-12 hours playing with this already. The more I learn, the more I think I'm going to like it.

Comment: I can't agree more with you! It looks too tempting already!

Comment: The official docs are being updated to clarify that you can only set the default value of an @api property. The parent component can always override the value.

Comment: @sfdcfox The operation you listed here not allowed inside `onclickhandler ` is actually allowed. Here is the link to the question on this (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255528/able-to-modilfy-api-in-compone-js-in-lightning-web-component). Can you look into this?