# `HTMLBridgeElement` constructor error in console

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am getting below error in console[image]

My line of codes where error is showing:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class WebComponentModal extends LightningElement {
    @api isModalOpen = false;
    @api shippingCharges = 0.00;
    @api SalesTax = 0.00;
    @api state = 'PA';
    @api check = false;
    @api customString;
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.customString = {st: this.state, shipping: this.shippingCharges, sales: this.SalesTax, chk: this.check};
}

    closeModal() {
        this.isModalOpen = false;
    }

   /* submitDetails(){
        this.isModalOpen = false; 
    }*/

    get options(){
        return[
            {label: 'PA', value: 'PA'},
            {label: 'NY', value: 'NY'},
            {label: 'NJ', value: 'NJ'} 
        ];
    }

    handleChange(event){
        this.state = event.detail.value;
        console.log(this.state);
        if(this.state == 'PA'){
            this.SalesTax = .06;
            this.shippingCharges = 2.99;
            this.check = true;
        }else if(this.state == 'NY'){
            this.SalesTax = .08;
            this.shippingCharges = 7.99;
            this.check = true;
        }else if(this.state == 'NJ'){
            this.SalesTax = .07;
            this.shippingCharges = 5.99;
            this.check = true;
        }

        this.isModalOpen = false;

        console.log(this.SalesTax);
        console.log(this.shippingCharges);

        this.customString = {st: this.state, shipping: this.shippingCharges, sales: this.SalesTax, chk: this.check};

        console.log(this.customString);

        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('custevent', {
            detail : this.customString
        });
        //dispatching the custom event
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);

        

    }
}
```

> The error is showing in customString at this.state. Infact similar
> error is showing for 'this.shippingcharges', 'this.salesTax',
> 'this.check'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you can't set `@api` values off of other values at that time, because the values aren't ready yet, and cannot be read. Use the `constructor()` method to set those values.

```
@api customString;
constructor() {
  super();
  this.customString = {
    st: this.state, 
    shipping: this.shippingCharges, 
    sales: this.SalesTax, 
    chk: this.check
  };
}
```

You must call `super()` first when overriding a class and providing a constructor. You can set any `@api` variables in the constructor. This is the last time you'll be allowed to set the value before it becomes read-only.

---

Edit: However, you can't read API values until it's too late to set those values. In all likelihood, you need to make `customString` a tracked variable instead:

```
@track customString;
```

And then set the value in the connectedCallback handler:

```
@track customString;
connectedCallback() {
  this.customString = {
    st: this.state, 
    shipping: this.shippingCharges, 
    sales: this.SalesTax, 
    chk: this.check
  };
}
```

Comment: i wonder constructor will work since public property value are not available in constructor according to lifecycle hooks. connectedCallback would be the right one.

Comment: @sanketkumar You cannot set `@api` values then. See [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/243728/2984).

Comment: I have updated my code, I need to update the values later in the code as well. Using constructor, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @user75908 Actually, I did some research. Apparently, you can't build API properties from other API this way. It should be `@track` instead.

Comment: check out this [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/pGu7yrjPg/9/edit) i have demonstrated what i mean to say. If it is connectedCallback, You can set the api value from other.

Comment: Using @track resolved the issue. Thanks sfdcfox.

Comment: @sanketkumar That seems contradictory to the documentation. I'll have to ask around about that.